# Debugging (stepping through) TypeScript Code, not the compiled Javascript

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript, web-essentials

I would like to be able to debug TypeScript 1.0 code using Visual Studio 2012 with Web Essentials.

According to this [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TvD_ia7vkkA), you firdst need to set the "Generate Source Map" option  to True to map the executing Javascript code to the original TypeScript source code.

Here's a snapshot from the video:

[image: Demoed Options]

However, look under Extensions andd Updates to see if I have the latest version of Web Essentials, it shows no Update available and that my version is 3.8. however, when I check my TypeScript options, there are much fewer options available and it does not include the "Mapping" option I am looking for:

[image]

I realize that TypeScript is new and evolving and I suspect that this functionality has possibly been de-implemented(?) but I was wondering what is the best and/or easiest way to step through TypeScript code?

Answer (score 1):

The functionality has been removed from Web Essentials and added to WebTools 2012.2, which you can find here.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-update

Now I can step through the TypeScript code directly. Very cool.

Comment: Just an FYI about direct typescript debugging. There is a caveat with debugging typescript (which like you said is very cool). If you use the this keyword (for example: this.XYZ), if you put a breakpoint on that line and add a watch on 'this', the value of this will always show as null. This is because when javascript is generated, this keyword is changed to _this. So, you will have to add watch on _this.XYZ instead of this.XYZ. This might be a bug for current release of Typescript. Not sure. If someone found a fix for this, please share it here.

Comment: Update: I'm frustrated that Compile on Save and the Step through debugging that was working with 2012 broke until I did this: https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Compile-on-Save. Then that fixed it on my VS 2012 work machine, but I cant get the debugging to work on my 2013 machine. Frustrating. Everything changes so fast its hard to know if even what you read is stillr elevant

Comment: Can you provide more details about what issue you are having.

Comment: Thanks for the offer. I'll create a seperate post and add a link here. thank you.